# Excel Graph Issue

Tags: c#, .net, excel, graph, charts

I'm trying to get the users in column 'A' displayed in the legend and the data next to the user in the bar. I'm not sure where the blank data is coming from nor why it's showing as 'Series'

I also want the left values to display from 0% to 100% so it's easier to read for the user by every 10%.

[image: img2]

[image: img]

```
      Excel.Range dataRange = chartSheet.get_Range("A1", "C" + chart.Rows.Count.ToString());
      //chart.Rows.Count = 2

                        Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)(excelWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing));
                        Excel.ChartObject newChartObject = chartObjects.Add(0, 600, 300, 300);

                        object paramChartFormat = 1;
                        object paramCategoryLabels = 0;
                        object paramSeriesLabels = 0;
                        bool paramHasLegend = true;
                        object paramTitle = "Performance Efficiency";
                        object paramCategoryTitle = "Providers";
                        object paramValueTitle = "Percentage";

                        newChartObject.Chart.ChartWizard(dataRange, Excel.XlChartType.xl3DColumn,
                            paramChartFormat, Excel.XlRowCol.xlRows, paramCategoryLabels,
                            paramSeriesLabels, paramHasLegend, paramTitle, paramCategoryTitle,
                            paramValueTitle, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Macro recorder is your friend... if you can do it directly in Excel and record a macro in the process chances are you'll figure out how to do it in code

Comment: You need to add a `Series.Name` to change the legend entries. I am not familiar with c# but it looks like you're assigning `paramSeriesLabels = 0` as the series labels, but this argument should be an array of string values to be used as the labels corresponding to each series. Likewise with the category labels on your X-axis (Provider Labels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I used to fix the issue

```
    Excel.Range dataRange = chartSheet.get_Range("B2", "B" + chart.Rows.Count.ToString());
    dataRange.NumberFormat = "#%";
    dataRange = chartSheet.get_Range("C2", "C" +   chart.Rows.Count.ToString());
                        dataRange.NumberFormat = "#%";

    dataRange = chartSheet.get_Range("A1", "C" + chart.Rows.Count.ToString());

    Excel.ChartObjects chartObjects = (Excel.ChartObjects)(excelWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing));
    Excel.ChartObject newChartObject = (Excel.ChartObject)chartObjects.Add(0, 600, (100 * chart.Rows.Count), 300);
    Excel.Chart chartPage = newChartObject.Chart;

    chartPage.SetSourceData(dataRange, Type.Missing);
    chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
```